# "No overload matches this call" error with React, Typescript, Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set certain documents when a user clicks on another users profile, to start a chat between them, the code works, my documents get created, but I have warnings and squiggly lines under the code where I am updating the doc for the users. Here is the code where the error is happening:

```
const handleSelect = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const combinedId =
    currentUser?.uid && user?.uid
      ? currentUser?.uid + user.uid + currentUser.uid
      : '';
  try {
    const res = await getDoc(doc(db, 'chats', combinedId));
    if(!res.exists()){
      await setDoc(doc(db, "chats", combinedId), {messages: []});
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser?.uid), {
        [combinedId + ".userInfo"]: {
          uid: user?.uid ?? '',
          displayName: user?.displayName ?? '',
          photoURL: user?.photoURL ?? ''
        },
        [combinedId+".date"]: serverTimestamp()
      });
      
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", user?.uid), {
        [combinedId + ".userInfo"]: {
          uid: currentUser?.uid ?? '',
          displayName: currentUser?.displayName ?? '',
          photoURL: currentUser?.photoURL ?? ''
        },
        [combinedId+".date"]: serverTimestamp()
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

The error is happening in the await updatedoc line for both the user and current user. If the code works, can I just ignore it?

Comment: please provide the `updateDoc( )` method

Comment: They are built in firebase functions